# Webpack: How to build single css file for main chunk with MiniCssExtractPlugin and multiple chunks?

Tags: css, webpack, styles, webpack-module-federation

In my webpack config i have two entries, "desktop" and "mobile".

Accoridng to documentation:

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#extracting-all-css-in-a-single-file

it possible to create single file of css, but with presented configuration styles in my project with multiple chunks webpack throws multiple warnings like:

```
WARNING in chunk styles [mini-css-extract-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[4].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/@soma-package/something/some/some.module.scss
```

In my project i use Module Federation with **bootstrap** file, created according to this documentation page:
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#troubleshooting

My `index.js` file looks like:

```js
import('./boostrap');
```

in addition, styles are collected incorrectly and blink

I tried to change webpack config like:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      '...',
      new CSSMinimizerWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        defaultVendors: false,
        styles: {
          name: (module, chunks) => chunks[0].runtime,
          type: 'css/mini-extract',
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

But with that config webpack throws error:

```
ERROR in SplitChunksPlugin
Cache group "styles" conflicts with existing chunk.
Both have the same name "desktop" and existing chunk is not a parent of the selected modules.
Use a different name for the cache group or make sure that the existing chunk is a parent (e. g. via dependsOn).
HINT: You can omit "name" to automatically create a name.
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to allow to use an entrypoint as splitChunk. This is no longer allowed when the entrypoint is not a parent of the selected modules.
Remove this entrypoint and add modules to cache group's 'test' instead. If you need modules to be evaluated on startup, add them to the existing entrypoints (make them arrays). See migration guide of more info.
```

How can i properly add all styles to single file in main chunk?

Comment: I had the exact same error even with a single entry point. I think it was caused by two modules in the same directory being dynamically imported in different parts of the code. One of the two imports didn't have a webpackChunkName magic comment, so the solution was to add the name in the import that didn't have it.